# Java - Synchronizing multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Assume that I have five threads running in various parts of my application - **A**, **B**, **C**, **D** and **E**. They do not have direct access to each other.

**A** cannot be allowed to run while **B**, **C**, **D** or **E** is running.

But **B**, **C**, **D** and **E** *can* all run at the same time.

How can I coordinate this in a simple, elegant way?

---

**EDIT**: To provide some more information, as requested:

**A** is a logout thread, that is triggered by a user action and sets a `currentUser` variable (accessible through a `LoginManager` singleton class)  to `null`.

All the others are various threads that use the `currentUser` object in multiple places throughout their run. The problem is that if the user logs out while **B** is running, then `currentUser` may become `null` before **B** is done accessing it. So I want the logout thread (**A**) to wait until **B** is done before completing the logout.

I *could* get `currentUser` once in the beginning of **B** and then pass it around as necessary through the duration of **B**, but that would mean changing dozens if classes and method signatures, just to pass this one variable around to a couple of places.

I also considered using `synchronized`, but as far as I know, that would make **B**, **C**, **D** and **E** mutually exclusive as well; not just with **A**.

I am running Java 7.

Comment: If you're on Java 8, take a look at the Executor interface.

Comment: Solution depends on scenario you are in and how your treats are related (if they aren't then you wound't need to synchronize them). You can search for solutions of [Readers–writers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem). Java has few classes which can solve different scenarios.

Comment: This looks like tipical writter-readers scenario. Some implementation of Read/Write lock should be exactly what you are looking for (with thread A requesting write access and threads B,C,D,E requesting read access)